# URL to use for webhook

Tags: salesforce, integration, docusignapi

I just want to ask if what are the possible solutions to provide a URL in our webhook in order to send a request from DocuSign to Salesforce

I have a DocuSign connected in Salesforce and we have implemented connection of the two using DocuSign Connect. It updates the DocuSign Status object in the Salesforce which helps our trigger to get the completed document from DocuSign and save it as a attachment. But now, we have removed the Connect because we are implementing REST and we need to create a webhook in order for DocuSign to send a request to Saleforce and update the DocuSign Status object based on the request. We have already created a webhook, but we were missing a URL that is needed by the webhook. I want to ask, how do we find this URL

Answer (score 0):

This url is the url for your own endpoint, on your own server. You need to have a public address for it, a DNS. You can use a cloud provider like Google, AWA or Azure so that they will give you a url where your code lives. The idea is that it's your url, so you need to know what it is.
oh, and it must be https, secure, cannot use http.